# Angular how to combine local function return value with runtime call back http request

Tags: rxjs, angular11

I have local function to check some validation which returns true/false. I also have runtime callback function which is an async function ie. http call.

Note: This checkPermission function is happening inside a for loop.

I want to check if any othese two function call is true. Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

```
private checkPermissions(
        moduleId: number,
        permissions: number[],
        callback?: () => Observable<boolean>
    ): boolean {
        if(callback) {
            console.log('callback function defined');
        }
```

//following is the local function. how to make callback() here?

```
        return this.userSecurityService.userHasLicenseAndPermission(
            moduleId,
            permissions
        );
    }
```

My complete code is:
Component:

```
options: NavOption[] = [];
this.options = this.sideNavService.loadMenus();
```

Sidenav service:

```
loadMenus(): NavOption[] {
    return this.getMenus();
}

private getMenus(): NavOption[] {
    const filteredMenuItems: NavOption[] = [];
    let menus =  [{
        id: 'recorded-events',
        label: 'Recorded events',
        icon: 'far fa-calendar-check fa-2x',
        url: `/incident/${this.organisationId}/list`,
        permissions: [
            EventReportingPermissions.View,
            EventReportingPermissions.ViewOwnEvents,
            EventReportingPermissions.ViewEmployeesEvents
        ],
        additionalPermissionCheck: () =>
            this.eventAccessGroupService.hasEventAccessGroupException()//this is the service to make http call
    },
    {
        id: 'new-events',
        label: 'Report new event',
        icon: 'far fa-calendar-plus fa-2x',
        url: `/incident/${this.organisationId}/create`,
        permissions: [EventReportingPermissions.Report]
    }]
    
    for(let item of menus) {
    
        let canAccess = this.checkPermissions(
                            topLevelItem.module,
                            subItem.permissions
                        );
        filteredMenuItems.push(item);
    }   
    return filteredMenuItems;
}

//local function

private checkPermissions(moduleId: number, permissions: number[]): boolean {
        //following returns value from local function and no http call
        return this.userSecurityService.userHasLicenseAndPermission(
            moduleId,
            permissions
        );
}

//additionalPermissionCheck?: () => Observable<boolean>;
```

Comment: Do you want to call `userHasLicenseAndPermission` inside `checkPermissions` function as callback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I am understanding correctly but is your callback the function that performs the permission checking?

If so you can use a `map` pipe:

```js
// Beware this returns Observable<boolean> and not boolean
const safeCallbackResult = callback ? callback() : of(true) // default to returning true as we'd like to check for the second condition
return callback().pipe(
  map(canDoAction => canDoAction ? this.userSecurityService.userHasLicenseAndPermission(...) : false)
)
```

If you'd like to return a boolean, you can't. Because the moment you need to *await* for the callback's observable emission that is an operation that can take some time. Even though you could make the function `async`

```js
private async checkPermissions(
  moduleId: number,  
  permissions: number[],
  callback?: () => Observable<boolean>
): Promise<boolean> {
  // callback().toPromise() if using RxJS 6
  // firstValueFrom(callback()) if using RxJS 7
  if(callback && ! (await callback().toPromise())) return false
  return this.userSecurityService.userHasLicenseAndPermission(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case if i use await inside the for loop will your code work? currently even before the value from await is returned the for loop is returned to the caller.

Comment: It should work. You can either `await` inside a for-loop or the `Promise.all` utility

Comment: Make sure to mark the function that has the `for` as `async` and `let canAccess = await checkPermissions(...)` otherwise you're not waiting for the check to finish and your for moves on with its life.

Comment: is there a way to chat to you directly if you dont mind?

Comment: Not sure we can do it on StackOverflow but you can message me on reddit (https://www.reddit.com/user/NanoSpicer) or over twitter @NanoSpicer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
sub = myHttpGetCall$().subscribe(value => {
        if (value && localValue) {
        // do whatever when both are true
        }
      }
```

Where localValue is the return value from your local function, which I assume is not an async operation.

Comment: hi @Deborahk, i have learnt Angular from scratch watching your videos from Pluralsight. Glad to receive your reply to my question. Thanks
I have updated my question above. I have to use await inside for loop. But right now, before the await gets the value, the for loop is exited and give the wrong result. 

Can you please have a look at my complete code above? Thanks

Comment: Great to hear! Hope you enjoyed the course. Have you seen the "RxJS in Angular: Reactive Development" course? It may help with using RxJS. Regarding this issue, it looks like you've accepted one of the above answers so I assume you've resolved the issue?

Comment: To be honest, i learnt angular only by watching your videos :). Yes i have watched RxJs. The above answer is using Promise, but i am looking with observable. As i am new to async/ await, i am looking for using async/await inside for loop with Observables. If you could help me with this would be great. Also let me know if there any way for me to contact you directly by chat. thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind words. I've not used async/await with an Observable. It would seem to negate the "reactive development" approach I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Use an RxJs `iif` https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif

```
booleanObservable$ = iif(() => yourLocalCondition, yourHttpRequest$, of(false));
```

If your localCondition is true it will make the http request otherwise there is no point so it just retuns an observable that emits false.